# Is my hashing function good enough

Tags: passwords, hash, php, salt, sha

Is there an obvious flaw with this hashing function (written in PHP)?

```
function hash($password) {
  sleep(1); // Make hashing slow
  $hash = "";
  $iterations = strlen($password);
  for ( $i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++ ) {
      $hash = hash('sha512', USER_PASSWORD_SALT . $password);
  }
  return $hash;
}
```

Comment: Slowing it down with the `sleep(1)` in your implementation doesn't directly affect attackers. May as well remove it.

Comment: Consider using the function password_hash instead, which does everything you're trying to do securely: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: @Simon is correct. Don't recreate the wheel. PHP does this already.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, there are obvious flaws. Here are some:

- You can’t make hashing slow by introducing simple delays. An attacker doesn’t have to evaluate the hash the same way you did; they just need to get the same answer in the end. That means whatever is making the hash slow needs to be a *necessary component* of the hash — it must be impossible to compute the hash without doing that. In fact, the `sleep(1)` is the kind of thing you have to *avoid*, in that it makes legitimate hashing slower than an attacker’s hashing (the whole point of hash design is to minimize the advantage of an attacker).
- The number of iterations is the length of the password. This isn’t enough. You want at least tens of thousands of iterations.
- The salt appears to be global. That’s not a salt; a salt has to be different for each user.
- This isn’t a standard algorithm. That means that it’s not a good idea to trust it for actual use. There are three algorithms with a fair amount of analysis (`scrypt`, `bcrypt`, PBKDF2). These have been looked at by actual cryptographers, and seem secure. Use one of them.
- The correct way to do a password hash in PHP is with the `password_hash` function, which handles everything for you (implementing an algorithm yourself is a poor idea for security just as much as creating your own algorithm is).

Comment: There's also the password hashing competition, which resulted in the Argon spec https://password-hashing.net/

Answer (score 1):

no. it looks like you're using a global constant for the salt. you want it to change per user record.

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999197/do-i-need-a-random-salt-once-per-password-or-only-once-per-database

also, @coverosgene is right - there's no point in slowing your own hash method down.